# What can I do if my Schengen visa isn't issued by my departure date?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I applied for Schengen student visa for France. My flight departure date is on the 9th of this month (3 days to go). However, my application is still in process.

If it is still being processed after the departure date, what are the chances of a visa being refused? Would I still stand a chance of getting a visa?

Comment: Forget worrying about the visa at this time you can't do anything about it while its still processing. Worry about your tickets because thats the money which will be lost if you don't show. Either move your ticket to a later date or refund it quickly before you lose all money on it

Comment: `I applied for Schengen student visa for france` When did you apply for the visa ?

Comment: The issuing of the Visa and your departure date are pretty much unrelated.  You chance of getting the Visa is exactly the same today as it will 4 days from now.  Right now, you need to worry about not losing all the money you paid for the flight.